# How can I show node.js queries in terminal?

Tags: node.js, express

I have made a demo app to do basic database operations. I am using mongoose and express modules. In the tutorial where I started to learn node in the terminal the following line (**PUT /flight/33/arrived 200 17ms - 22b**) I could see. What I am missing from my code?

[image]

UPDATE

Thanks Esteban! This what I have done:
terminal > **npm install morgan**

code:

```
var morgan = require('morgan');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the logging middleware. It's [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) for express 4. You can check out an example of how it's set up [in the docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use).